# is if else conditions available on htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess file in the folder "services" in my website
and have to give two urls following

content of htaccess

```
#------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?n=$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
$-------------------------

1. http://www.mysite.com/services/seo-work
2. http://www.mysite.com/services/online-editor
```

The 1st URL rewritten using htaccess like `http://www.mysite.com/services/index.php?s=seo-work`
This is working correct. but when i am uploading other file online-editor.php on the same folder "services", it is not working

so how the first url should show the page using index.php?s=seo-work if the page "online-editor.php" is not found in directory otherwise online-editor.php shoud show. I am programatically representing my problem below

```
if(IsFoundPageInDirectory(online-editor.php))
{
   GoToUrl(http://www.mysite.com/services/online-editor.php)
}
else
{
   GoToUrl(http://www.mysite.com/services/index.php?s=seo-work)
}
```

Please help me to get out of this problem
Advance thanks for your reply

Answer (score 8):

There is not really `if/else` conditions with `ifModule` in Apache configuration, but you can use the test in 2 cases : `!module` & `module`, like this:

```
<IfModule !module>
  # default directives
</IfModule>

<IfModule module>
  # decorator directives
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check default wordpress .htaccess file. I think you're missing checks for existing files and directories. Something like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.
Its working but I should be included the .php on the file..
I need to eliminate .php also from the url

Answer (score 0):

Last I found answer.. thanks for the fist reply to lead me to get answer

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?n=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```